# Javascript - difference in exporting

Tags: javascript, singleton, export

Is there any difference between those 2?

foo1.js

```
class Foo {
...
}

module.exports = new Foo();
```

bar1.js

```
import Foo from 'foo1.js'
```

foo2.js

```
class Foo2 {
...
}
export default Foo2;
```

bar2.js

```
import foo from 'foo2.js'
let Foo = new foo();
```

To my understanding the first way produces a singleton, while in the second way I can have as many instances I want. Is this right? What's the benefit in JS of having a singleton, given the fact that you can work with states in a different manner (redux, flux) ?

Comment: Is this question about singletons, state management in JavaScript or the import/export syntax?

Comment: You can still access `Foo.constructor` and instantiate a new object.

Comment: @PeterMader It's about both, but more focused on the behaviour of the two syntaxes